# AirLowFareSearchRQ not working anymore?

Tags: web-services, sabre

I'm not able to get results for my query since this morning. Anyone else had this same error ?

It's somehow saying that the version is deprecated and that it will be replaced with the new release. But I don't remember I received any notification about this upgrade. :/

Thank you for your help.

Request:

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ PrimaryLangID="fr" Version="1.4.0" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
 <POS>
  <Source PseudoCityCode="9TB9">
   <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
     <CompanyName Code="##">####</CompanyName>
   </RequestorID>
  </Source>
 </POS>
 <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
  <DepartureDateTime>2017-05-13T13:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
  <DepartureWindow>11001500</DepartureWindow>
  <OriginLocation LocationCode="NCE"/>
  <DestinationLocation LocationCode="PAR"/>
  <TPA_Extensions>
   <SegmentType Code="O"/>
  </TPA_Extensions>
 </OriginDestinationInformation>
 <TravelPreferences MaxStopsQuantity="2"/>
  <TravelerInfoSummary>
   <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
   <AirTravelerAvail>
    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ITX" Quantity="1"/>
   </AirTravelerAvail>
   <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="EUR">
    <TPA_Extensions>
     <PublicFare Ind="false"/>
     <PrivateFare Ind="true"/>
     <Priority>
       <Price Priority="1"/>
       <DirectFlights Priority="2"/>
       <Time Priority="3"/>
       <Vendor Priority="4"/>
     </Priority>
   </TPA_Extensions>
  </PriceRequestInformation>
 </TravelerInfoSummary>
 <TPA_Extensions>
  <IntelliSellTransaction>
   <RequestType Name="100ITINS"/>
  </IntelliSellTransaction>
 </TPA_Extensions>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

Response:

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS Version="1.4.0" PricedItinCount="0" BrandedOneWayItinCount="0" SimpleOneWayItinCount="0" DepartedItinCount="0" SoldOutItinCount="0" AvailableItinCount="0" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Errors>
  <Error Type="SCHEDULES" Code="PROCESS" ShortText="Communication error code=104: Connection reset by peer"/>
  <Error Type="IF2" Code="PROCESS" ShortText="No complete journey can be built in IF2/ADVJR1."/>
  <Error Type="MAIN" Code="DEPRECATEDRS" ShortText="This response version is deprecated and will be decommissioned once two newer versions are released."/>
  <Error Type="WORKERTHREAD" Code="TRANSACTIONID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="3418533871368693570"/>
  <Error Type="SERVER" Code="TTFHLP683" MessageClass="I" ShortText="27042"/>
  <Error Type="DEFAULT" Code="RULEID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="18561"/>
  <Error Type="DRE" Code="RULEID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="15957"/>
  <Error Type="SCHEDULES" Code="MSG" MessageClass="I" ShortText="NO FLIGHT SCHEDULES FOR QUALIFIERS USED"/>
  <Error Type="ERR" Code="ERR" ShortText="Error during Processing"/>
 </Errors>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is working again now so you can consider this as solved !

Comment: Did it just resumed working by itself or you changed anything there to make it work. I am having a similar problem here after uploading to an online server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code directly from github, make sure you change code in to `BargainFinderMaxSoapActivity` class's `getRequest` method. They did put Date-Time and locations hard coded. So its not picking up one you are feeding in form.